# How can I draw a landscape picture using PSTricks?

Tags: pstricks, rotating, landscape

I need to draw a figure using PSTricks which is quite a bit wider than than it is long. Is there anyway I can draw a pic like that in a landscape mode?

Right now my pic starts at the top of a regular page and expands as it goes down but only has 8.5 inches to expand (in an A4 paper 8.5x11 ) into but if I could draw it landscape then I would have 11 inches for my bottom row. I need to write more stuff into it than is written in the MWE and that's why I would love to be able to draw my tree Landscape. I hope I am making sense here.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{graphicx}              % to include figures
\usepackage{amsmath}               % great math stuff
\usepackage{amsfonts}              % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{amsthm}                % better theorem environments
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node,pst-tree}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(14,22)
%\psgrid(14,22)
\rput(7,21){\ovalnode{0}{Alpha}}
\rput(3,17){\ovalnode{01}{Beta 1}}
\rput(11,17){\ovalnode{02}{Beta 2}}
\rput(0,13){\ovalnode{011}{Gamma 1}}
\rput(4,13){\ovalnode{012}{Gamma 2}}
\rput(8,13){\ovalnode{021}{Gamma 3}}
\rput(13,13){\ovalnode{022}{Gamma 4}}
\ncline{->}{0}{01}\mput*{Choice 1}
\ncline{->}{0}{02}\mput*{Choice 2}
\ncline{->}{01}{011}\mput*{Choice 1}
\ncline{->}{01}{012}\mput*{Choice 2}
\ncline{->}{02}{021}\mput*{Choice 1}
\ncline{->}{02}{022}\mput*{Choice 2}
\end{pspicture}

\end{figure} 


\end{document}
```

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

I'd really appreciate it if you can tell me how to do it inside my Latex code.

Comment: You can wrap the entire content of the `pspicture` using `\rput{-90}{...}` to rotate it 90 degrees clockwise. However, you may also consider creating the tree using [`pst-tree`](http://ctan.org/pst-tree) rather than creating it by hand.

Comment: Could also be a job for the `sidewaysfigure` environment from »[rotating](http://ctan.org/pkg/rotating)«.

Comment: Thanks Werner. My picture has gone from left to right. I will play around with pst-tree to see if it makes my life easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, one way to do this is to wrap the contents of your `pspicture` in an `\rput{-90}(<xcoord>,<ycoord>)`

[image]

Your current implementation uses `pst-node`; it might also make sense to have a look at `pst-tree` for this particular graphic.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}  % set the margins to 1in on all sides
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\begin{pspicture}(0,7)(14,24)
%\psgrid
\rput{-90}(-8,22){
    \rput(7,21){\ovalnode{0}{Alpha}}
    \rput(3,17){\ovalnode{01}{Beta 1}}
    \rput(11,17){\ovalnode{02}{Beta 2}}
    \rput(0,13){\ovalnode{011}{Gamma 1}}
    \rput(4,13){\ovalnode{012}{Gamma 2}}
    \rput(8,13){\ovalnode{021}{Gamma 3}}
    \rput(13,13){\ovalnode{022}{Gamma 4}}
    \ncline{->}{0}{01}\mput*{Choice 1}
    \ncline{->}{0}{02}\mput*{Choice 2}
    \ncline{->}{01}{011}\mput*{Choice 1}
    \ncline{->}{01}{012}\mput*{Choice 2}
    \ncline{->}{02}{021}\mput*{Choice 1}
    \ncline{->}{02}{022}\mput*{Choice 2}
}
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure} 


\end{document}
```