# How to put a brace and a title?

Tags: tikz-pgf, titles, braces

I would like to put a brace between the Q_s and Q_d of the following diagram

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5,scale=1,thick]
\usetikzlibrary{calc}   %allows coordinate calculations.

%Define linear parameters for supply and demand
\def\dint{4.5}          %Y-intercept for DEMAND.
\def\dslp{-0.5}         %Slope for DEMAND.
\def\sint{1.2}          %Y-intercept for SUPPLY.
\def\sslp{0.8}          %Slope for SUPPLY.

\def\pfc{2.5}           %Price floor or ceiling

\def\demand{\x,{\dslp*\x+\dint}}
\def\supply{\x,{\sslp*\x+\sint}}

% Define coordinates.
    \coordinate (ints) at ({(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)},{(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)*\sslp+\sint});
    \coordinate (ep) at  (0,{(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)*\sslp+\sint});
    \coordinate (eq) at  ({(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)},0);
    \coordinate (dint) at (0,{\dint});
    \coordinate (sint) at (0,{\sint});
    \coordinate (pfq) at  ({(\pfc-\dint)/(\dslp)},0);
    \coordinate (pfp) at  ({(\pfc-\dint)/(\dslp)},{\pfc});
    \coordinate (sfq) at  ({(\pfc-\sint)/(\sslp)},0);
    \coordinate (sfp) at  ({(\pfc-\sint)/(\sslp)},{\pfc});

% DEMAND
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot (\demand) node[right] {$P(q) = -\frac{1}{2}q+\frac{9}{2}$};

% SUPPLY
    \draw[thick,color=purple] plot (\supply) node[right] {Supply};

% Draw axes, and dotted equilibrium lines.
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[right] {$Q$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6.2) node[above] {$P$};

    %Price floor and ceiling lines
    \draw[dashed,color=black] plot (\x,{\pfc}) node[right] {$P_c$};
    \draw[dashed] (pfp) -- (pfq) node[below] {$Q_d$};
    \draw[dashed] (sfp) -- (sfq) node[below] {$Q_s$};

\draw[->,baseline=5] ($(0,{\pfc})+(-1.5,0.7)$) node[label= left:Price Ceiling] {} -- ($(0,{\pfc})+(-.1,0.1)$);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The result of the code above WITHOUT the brace wanted is:

[image]

Also I would like to know how to make a title when I'm making the above diagram using

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
```

Comment: To make the problem clearer: you'd like to have a brace from the left side of *Qs* to the right side of *Qd*, below them?

Comment: @egreg exactly this is what i want

Comment: Can you take a look at [How to join underbrace/overbrace between nodes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/how-to-join-underbrace-overbrace-between-nodes) to see if that helps you?

Comment: I'll check this out. But what about the title?

Comment: @Jake I don't know how to achieve what I want by using the instructions of what you gave me. For example it shows an error with the axes. what should i do? is there another solution?

Comment: What do you mean by a title? Is is some kind of description for the diagram? Where should this title appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the braces, you can use a `brace` decoration (from the `decorations.pathreplacing` library); for the title, you can use a `\node` placed at `(current bounding box.north)` (or any other desired location), for example:

```
\documentclass[class=minimal,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:5,scale=1,thick]

%Define linear parameters for supply and demand
\def\dint{4.5}          %Y-intercept for DEMAND.
\def\dslp{-0.5}         %Slope for DEMAND.
\def\sint{1.2}          %Y-intercept for SUPPLY.
\def\sslp{0.8}          %Slope for SUPPLY.

\def\pfc{2.5}           %Price floor or ceiling

\def\demand{\x,{\dslp*\x+\dint}}
\def\supply{\x,{\sslp*\x+\sint}}

% Define coordinates.
    \coordinate (ints) at ({(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)},{(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)*\sslp+\sint});
    \coordinate (ep) at  (0,{(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)*\sslp+\sint});
    \coordinate (eq) at  ({(\sint-\dint)/(\dslp-\sslp)},0);
    \coordinate (dint) at (0,{\dint});
    \coordinate (sint) at (0,{\sint});
    \coordinate (pfq) at  ({(\pfc-\dint)/(\dslp)},0);
    \coordinate (pfp) at  ({(\pfc-\dint)/(\dslp)},{\pfc});
    \coordinate (sfq) at  ({(\pfc-\sint)/(\sslp)},0);
    \coordinate (sfp) at  ({(\pfc-\sint)/(\sslp)},{\pfc});

% DEMAND
    \draw[thick,color=blue] plot (\demand) node[right] {$P(q) = -\frac{1}{2}q+\frac{9}{2}$};

% SUPPLY
    \draw[thick,color=purple] plot (\supply) node[right] {Supply};

% Draw axes, and dotted equilibrium lines.
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (6.2,0) node[right] {$Q$};
    \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,6.2) node[above] {$P$};

    %Price floor and ceiling lines
    \draw[dashed,color=black] plot (\x,{\pfc}) node[right] {$P_c$};
    \draw[dashed] (pfp) -- (pfq) node[below] (qd) {$Q_d$};
    \draw[dashed] (sfp) -- (sfq) node[below] (qs) {$Q_s$};

\draw[->,baseline=5] ($(0,{\pfc})+(-1.5,0.7)$) node[label= left:Price Ceiling] {} -- ($(0,{\pfc})+(-.1,0.1)$);

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] (qs.south) -- node[below] {some text} (qd.south);

\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror}] 
  ([yshift=-1.2cm]0,0) -- node[below] {some text} ([yshift=-1.2cm]6.2,0);

\node at ([yshift=10pt]current bounding box.north) {A diagram illustrating supply versus demand};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How I could put a brace to x-axis from the beginning until the end of the axis? I would like to put under the under brace.

Comment: @giannis please see my updated answer.

Comment: could we fill in with a pattern of lines the gap between the red and the blue line?

Comment: @giannis that's a new issue, not related to the original question, so I think the thing to do is for you to open a fresh new question with this new requirement.